# Dynamic URL paths in Nuxt JS / Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

Nuxt JS creates its routes based on the file system. You typically require templates to be set up for the dynamic params, like `_id.vue` etc.

However, my backend developer has a CMS that spits out JSON with links to pages that sit on entirely dynamic URL's.

e.g. `/about-us/people/michael/`

There's no way for me to know ahead of time how these kinds of URL's should be routed with Nuxt's file-based system.

Some links could look like: `/articles/hello-world/` etc.

Is there any info on how I can capture all routes, no matter how far the nesting goes?

I'm able to do the first level by having `index.vue` and `_slug.vue`, (e.g. `/about-us/`). Beyond that, it's a mystery how I'd solve having `/about-us/people/` etc without it throwing a **404**.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#extendroutes)

```
module.exports = {
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'catchall',
        path: '*',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/catchallpage.vue')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the route I end up going down. Thanks.